# Has jboss to be in domain mode to use shared cache?

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan, jboss-eap-7

I have 2 jboss that run in standalone mode.
I'd like to configure the infinispan module so that the cache is shared between nodes: if I put an element in jboss 1's cache I want to get it in the jboss 2.

Maybe I'm unlucky but I cannot find any guide about that...is that because the only  the domain mode supports this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Domain vs standalone mode merely determines how servers should be managed.  Clustering is an orthogonal concept.  Both domain mode and standalone mode contain "HA" profiles.  The infinispan cache configurations in the these profiles are distributed by default.